# Add docker container to network under two different names

Tags: networking, docker, containers, docker-compose

I am experimenting with the new docker networking feature. I migrated my old setup using container links to the new bridge network; so far, I have my dedicated bridge network up and running among multiple containers on the same host.
Now I am looking for a means to replicate multiple link aliases for the same container.

Say, I have a container named `myBox` that joins the docker network. I want to have the same container also reachable as `myServer`.
Using links, I would simply set up two links with different aliases.
Is there a means to achieve this using docker networking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is being specified and implemented in [docker/libnetwork issue 737](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/737)

> We'd like a container to be able to join a network under different names, not just the container name.

That will help `docker compose` too: see [docker/compose issue 2312](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2312).

> When using the `--x-networking` feature in docker-compose 1.5 (docker-engine 1.9), is it possible to get a "simple name" added to `/etc/hosts` without knowing the container name beforehand and without using the `container_name` directive?

[Update January 2016](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2312#issuecomment-172901433):

> This is now done in 1.6.0 (RC1 is out)

See "[Networking in Compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/1.6.0-rc1/docs/networking.md)"

Note: The experimental flags `--x-networking` and `--x-network-driver`, introduced in Compose 1.5, have been removed.

See [PR 19242](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19242/files) and [`docker network connect`](https://github.com/mavenugo/docker/blob/dda513ef651b42fcb9625e651f664554161c0a6a/docs/reference/commandline/network_connect.md):

> `--alias` option can be used to resolve the container by another name in the network being connected to.

```
$ docker network connect --alias db --alias mysql multi-host-network container2
```

Also:

> You can use --link option to link another container with a prefered alias

```
$ docker network connect --link container1:c1 multi-host-network container2
```

Comment: Note that `--link` is considered a legacy option and [may be removed eventually](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/).

Comment: Also, another option is: `docker run --link myBox:myServerAlias my-client-image`

Comment: @MassoodKhaari I agree. That answer was initially written in 2015, at a time where `--link` was all there was. Since then `network connect` is the preferred option.