# 2 seperate docker stacks can't communicate over 172.x network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In order to debug and setup a pair of docker stacks (one is a client and other a server along with their own private services they each require) using docker compose, I'm running them locally to make sure they're functioning correctly.

They will eventually be communicating across the internet with a nginx server on the server side to act as a reverse proxy. But for now, i'm specifying the client use the 172.19.0.3:1234 address of the server container.

I'm able to `curl`/`ping` both the client container and server container from the host machine, but running an interactive session and trying to `curl` the server's 172.19.0.3:1234 address just times out.

I feel the 172.x is being used incorrectly here. Is their some obvious issue with what I've described so far? What is the better approach for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Just an additional note: Before using compose, I was using containers directly and didn't have this issue of communicating across the 172.x network between containers. Seems like compose is creating a 'isolated' network that can't be reached from other docker compose networks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that after doing some searching, I am in a similar situation to this question: [Communicating between Docker containers in different networks on the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035595/communicating-between-docker-containers-in-different-networks-on-the-same-host).

I've decided to use `docker network connect` to connect the client to the server's network for my purposes.