# Connecting 2 different docker Container in two different network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am trying to create a virtual environment for a university project.
I need to create two different containers which are hosted on the same pc, but they must be into two different networks. One Container needs to ping the other container
Any suggestion on how can I do it?

Here it is the docker-compose that I created:

```
version: "3.7"
services: 
 client:
  build: "./Client_Coap_Amplification_Attack"
  image: "/pythonclient:latest"
  networks:
   - rete


 server:
  build: "./Server_Coap_Amplification_Attack"
  image: "/mynode:latest"
  container_name: server
  ports:
  - "8081:5683"
  networks: 
   rete_server: 
    ipv4_address: 172.19.1.2

networks: 
 rete:
  ipam: 
   driver: default
   config: 
    - subnet: "172.19.0.0/24"
 rete_server:
  ipam:
   driver: default
   config:
    - subnet: "172.19.1.0/24"
```

Thanks fot the help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between Docker containers in different networks on the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035595/communicating-between-docker-containers-in-different-networks-on-the-same-host)

Comment: @tgogos probably you are right, but I have one more issue. I have to create a script which modifies the IP table to permit the connection between the two dockers that are into two different networks. I need to know before the interfaces of the containers. How can I do it?

Comment: I did a quick test with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51373066/1561148) and it seems to work. To find the `br-******` names I used the `ip route` command and got something like: `172.18.0.0/16 dev br-1d73919f58e5 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1` and `172.19.0.0/16 dev br-86d321a0513e proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1`

Comment: @tgogos I am still working for a solution. I don't know if I was clear in asking my question. I want 2 hosts that are in two different networks. Each host mustn't be natted by the networks (I want a public address for them). How can I do it?