# Docker: Create Multiple Names for a container

Tags: docker

We used to run docker images to create the respective container with a custom name using `--name` flag as below.

```
docker run --name=randome-test3 -d  random-q:v0.1
```

When I list the containers

```
trivia_docker docker container ls -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1a89e35aacb5        random-q:v0.1       "/bin/bash /code/ran…"   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                            testing
```

Here field says `Names`, so just with curiosity, is it possible to give multiple names to a container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can specify different names for your container to add it into multiple docker networks.

If you want to find out more how you can do it, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34038381/10717279