# How does someone give a docker container 2 names?

Tags: docker, containers

Before restarting our server, I took note of all the docker containers that were running on it.  Some containers were started by people no longer with the company so I'm not sure how they were started up but these services are still being used by various other people within the company.  One of the entries was this:

```
b69f0c8a730   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld"    19 months ago    Up 19 months    33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49152->3306/tcp   dsmith_myadmin/db,dsmith_mysql
```

This service didn't automatically come back up on its own.  I found a stopped container with the name (dsmith_mysql) and executed

> docker start dsmith_mysql

but the entry doesn't show this double name.  The name of the container is just dsmith_mysql.

> docker inspect dsmith_mysql

also isn't telling me what I want to know.  Can anyone tell me how someone could start a container with this double name?

Comment: Can't you use the container ID instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247227/docker-create-multiple-names-for-a-container ?

Comment: I think that format could come from the obsolete Docker link functionality.  I wouldn't specifically worry about trying to reproduce it.